# How to clear or mask certain areas of a glow (effect)?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, mask, effects

I need to clear the outside glow (in the green area) in order to have the glow only in the inside area of the diamond

[image]

I've tried the eraser tool and a layer mask but no success. The only way that I can clear the effect is clearing the actual shape, but that's not what I need

[image]

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the effect (outer glow) in the layer palette and select "Create layer".

Now the glow effect is simply a layer like anything else. Select the part(s) of it you do not require and either delete them (not recommended) or apply a mask (pro style haha)

If you choose the wise path and embrace masks, then simply select the area you do not require, hit <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> to invert, and hit the "Add layer mask" button in the layer panel.

I suppose you could just select the part you want to *keep* and hit the layer mask button, but that has simply never occurred to me until now!

Joking apart, turning effects into standard layers is an important concept that will serve you well going forwards.

Comment: This is great!
I suppose if I need to make changes to the effect after I made it a layer I simply can't, so I may need to make a copy of it before in order to always have the base settings of the effect to be able to modify them later
Thanks and greetings!

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is to convert the vector shape layer (together with its effects) into a Smart Object, then apply a vector mask to the Smart Object.

This method allows you to edit everything later if necessary, since it's non-destructive. The effects will still be editable live effects inside the Smart Object.

For example:

[image]

I can double click the Smart Object afterwards, change the effects, fills, etc, then close the Smart Object, agree to save the changes, and the result is updated in the original image.

[image]

After editing the fill colour, and glow colour.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to put it in a group with a mask.

[image]

[image]

Or in this case one could use as well a clipping mask (And use Layer styles to apply only on the bright areas to keep the border)